# Is there a maximum number of points that can be plotted with gvisMap? or gvisMap wont plot all points

Tags: r, ggvis, ggmap, googlevis

**EDIT**
After three days of little interest, I am adding a fully reproducible example... The code below makes 1400 locations.  The first 700 points are centered around the first area, the 2nd 700 points are centered around a 2nd area to the northwest.

```
datOne <- data.frame(
  Long = runif(700, -111.180000, -110.950000 ),
  Lat = runif(700, 43.180000, 43.440000),
  Area = "First")

datTwo <- data.frame(
  Long = runif(700, -111.850000, -110.900000),
  Lat = runif(700, 43.910000, 44.000000),
  Area = "Second")

dat <- rbind(datOne, datTwo)
dat$LatLong <- paste(dat$Lat, dat$Long, sep = ":")

head(dat)
       Long      Lat  Area                            LatLong
1 -110.9701 43.19509 First 43.1950901590148:-110.970063584852
2 -111.0258 43.25338 First 43.2533758980362:-111.025837010061
3 -111.1737 43.18016 First  43.180157370572:-111.173737878765
4 -111.1130 43.41193 First 43.4119294773275:-111.112970910808
5 -110.9909 43.34044 First 43.3404393909033:-110.990947539737
6 -110.9800 43.33428 First 43.3342766285082:-110.979969937215
```

If I try to plot the points with `gvisMap` then only the locations centered around the first area apear in the map as is reproduced with the following code

```
library(googleVis)
M2 <- gvisMap(dat, "LatLong", 
              options=list(showLine=TRUE, enableScrollWheel=TRUE, 
                           mapType='satlite', useMapTypeControl=TRUE, 
                           width="800", height="800",
                           colors = "['#0000ff']",
                           icons=paste0("{","'default': {'normal':
                                        'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle.png',\n",
                                        "'selected':'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle.png'",
                                        "}}")
              ))
plot(M2)
```

To confirm that all the locations are formatted correctly I can subset the dataframe to plot points 500:1000 which includes locations in both areas. Changing the first line of code to

```
M2 <- gvisMap(dat[500:1000, ], "LatLong",
```

will correctly display locations in both areas.  So, the issue does not seem to be formatting, but maybe there is a maximum number of points that can be plotted..?

Is it possible to plot all locations in the reproducible data included herein?

Any suggestions or code to plot all of the points in the `dat`dataframe above would be greatly appreciated.  I am happy to take suggested code from other packages such as `leaflet` mentioned in the comments.

Comment: leaflet might be a better option.

Comment: cool. leaflet also looks like a good option.  That being said, the existing code with `gvisMap` should also work fine for my needs, except for the odd issue in the OP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the example below. This uses the R leaflet package and binds a popup to the markers from the area column.

```
library(leaflet)

datOne <- data.frame(
  lng = runif(700, -111.180000, -110.950000 ),
  lat = runif(700, 43.180000, 43.440000),
  Area = "First")

datTwo <- data.frame(
  lng = runif(700, -111.850000, -110.900000),
  lat = runif(700, 43.910000, 44.000000),
  Area = "Second")

dat <- rbind(datOne, datTwo)
dat$latLng <- paste(dat$lat, dat$lng, sep = ":")

map<-leaflet(dat)
map<-addTiles(map)
map<-addMarkers(map,~lng,~lat,popup = ~as.character(Area))
map
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw this into the mix here, as the question is about maximum number of points. In case you ever find yourselves in the need of plotting points (or polygons or lines) in the order of tens of thousands or millions, **mapview** would be an option:

```
library(mapview)
library(sp)

datOne <- data.frame(
  lng = runif(70000, -111.180000, -110.950000 ),
  lat = runif(70000, 43.180000, 43.440000),
  Area = "First")

coordinates(datOne) <- ~ lng + lat
proj4string(datOne) <- "+init=epsg:4326"

mapview(datOne)
```

Note that **mapview** only works with spatial classes, therefore needs a valid `proj4string()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a maximum number of points that can be displayed using Google Maps API, through `googleVis`

As noted here: [https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map#data-format]

*Note: The Lat-Long pairs option loads maps much faster, especially with large data. We recommend that you use this option for large data sets. Please visit Google Maps API to find out how to transform your addresses to lat-long points. The map can display a maximum of 400 entries; if your data holds more than 400 rows, only the first 400 will be shown.*

The above `leaflet` works great for data sets larger than 400 points.